# OBjective-C : Use NSTimer while the app is close

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

it is possible to use a timer that is working when the application is closed? and when the timer is finish it send a push notification ??

thx

Comment: kubi: I rolled back your tag edit because it isn't clear that this question is about the iPhone. Push notifications exist on the Mac, too: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3947

Answer (score 2):

No, when your application isn't running, you can't have any timers going either.

The push notification would have to come from outside (for example, from a server you run).

(I'm assuming this is an iPhone question)

Comment: ok so it is possible to do it but on my own push notification server